# Cant convert object of type java.util.Arraylist Read from Firebase realtim database nested objects

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> This Firebase database structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIjX8.png)

> Here is my Device Class:

```
public class Device {

private String title;
private Map<String,Counters> CounterNumber;
private Counters counters;

public void setCounter(Map<String,Counters> CounterNumber){
    this.CounterNumber=CounterNumber;
}
public Map<String,Counters> getCounter(){
    return CounterNumber;
}
public Counters getCounters(){
    return counters;
}
public void setCounters(Counters counters){
    this.counters=counters;
}
public Device(){

}
public Device(String title){
    this.title=title;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title=title;
}
```

}

```
Second class is my nested object I think
```

> Second class Counters Class My Problem is I don't know how to read `Counter` object from the database with `FirebaseUI` and `RecycleView`.

```
public class Counters implements Serializable {
private String countername;
private String counternumber;
public Counters (){

}
public Counters(String counternumber,String countername){
    this.counternumber=counternumber;
    this.countername=countername;
}
public String getCounterName() {
    return countername;
}

public void setCounterName(String counterName) {
    this.countername = countername;
}

public String getCounterNumber() {
    return counternumber;
}

public void setCounterNumber(String counternumber) {
    this.counternumber = countername;
}
```

}

> This My HomeActivity Here read from firebase objects

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    mDevice=new ArrayList<Device>();
    mdevices=new Device();

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                try {
                    for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        ArrayList<String> counterse= (ArrayList<String>) eventSnapshot.getValue();
                        Log.e(TAGE, counterse.toString());
                        Device device = eventSnapshot.getValue(Device.class);
                        String id = eventSnapshot.getKey();
                        Counters counters = eventSnapshot.child(id).getValue(Counters.class);
                        device.setCounters(counters);
                        mDevice.add(device);
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }

            }
            displayDevices();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
private void displayDevices(){
    options=
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Device>()
                    .setQuery(databaseReference.child("devices").orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(userid),Device.class).build();


    adapter=
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Device, MyRecyclerViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Device model) {

                    mdevices=mDevice.get(position);
                    holder.txt_title.setText(model.getTitle());
                    holder.txt_counter.setText(mdevices.getCounters().getCounterNumber());
                    Log.i(TAG,mdevices.getCounters().getCounterNumber());

                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public MyRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.device_list,parent,false);
                    return new MyRecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
                }
            };

    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
@Override
public void onStart() {
   adapter.startListening();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

> Here is my Error Code
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKJfi.png)

Comment: I think the way you are modelling counters is wrong. Try using `List<Counter> counters` in your `Device` class instead of using `Counters`. The `Counter` model class is the same as your current `Counters` class. A rule while naming model classes is to always use singular name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.smartappfirebase.Counters

Because you getting an `ArrayList` object and **not** a `Counters` object and there is no way in Java to create such a cast. Your `counters` node that exists within the `cRVh ... NHeT` node is actually an array. When you try to read that array in code, it is read as an ArrayList, hence that error. As I see in your screenshot, that array contains `Counters` objects. Unfortunately, you cannot simply map that array of `Counters` objects to an `ArrayList<Counters>`. The `counters` node is actually an ArrayList of HashMaps. So if you need to have an `ArrayList<Counters>`, then you should iterate and create that List yourself. Besides that, the name of the properties in your `Counters` class do **not** match the names in the database. See, `countername` vs `name` and `counternumber` vs `counter`. All properties must match.

Comment: Thank you for help, but I am newbie in android development, I don't know how to create this list, if you have time for this please help explain example code.

Comment: I understand that you are a newbie but you should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to cast HashMap to ArrayList.
Though, you may try to get `keys()` or `values()` of the HashMap.

And you should post full exception log, not as image.

Comment: I understand you but, how use FirebaseRecyclerView adapter?

Answer (score 0):

> I try to change
>
> ```
>  Arraylist
> ```

```
package com.example.smartappfirebase;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Device{

```
private String title;
private ArrayList<counters> counters;

public ArrayList<counters> getCounter() {
    return counters;
}

public void setCounter(ArrayList<counters> counters) {
    this.counters = counters;
}

public Device(){}

public Device(String title,ArrayList<counters> counters) {
    this.title = title;
    this.counters=counters;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

}

> Result is:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
```